# Javascript literal nested object - refer to top level properties

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a client side for mobile app that work with restful style web services.

```
var globApp = {
    sessionId : "",
    lastActionName: "",
    userName : "2victor",
    md5Pwd : "1234",
    hostApiPath : "http://host/api",
    action : {
        login : {
            scriptPath : "/acc/login",
            method : "PUT",
            requestParams : {
                user : this.userName,
                pwd : this.md5pwd
            },
            responseParams : {

            }
        },
        register : {
            scriptPath : "/acc/reg",
            method : "POST",
            requestParams : {
                user : "myUserName",
                fname : "myFirstName" ,
                lname : "myLastName" ,
                email : "mail@mail.com" ,
                age : "28" ,
                gender : "male" ,
                pwd : "1234" ,
                priv : "good"
            },
            responseParams : {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Properties userName and md5pwd will be assigned when application start.
What I want to achieve is, to assign this values to user and pwd properties under requestParams object for each action. Of course using this doesn't work and return undefined cause this in that case refers to the nested object if I understand correct.

This requestParams object is sent as JSON by AJAX.

I can define few variables out of this object and use them but I don't want to.

How it can be done?

Comment: It can't be done with an object literal. You have to add the properties that depend on others in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. The object is not available in any way until it has been fully defined. So you can't do it on one single step.

Comment: what is the other options? is it can be done if I declare the globApp object with 'new'?

Comment: No. You cannot do it using just one statement. You could create the object without those values and then assign them in additional statements though.